# Ionic Page content gets cut off when PDF printing

Tags: css, angular, pdf, ionic3

I have an Ionic Page that is a long list of Questions/Answers that is intended to be printed to PDF by the user using the browser print to PDF functionality.

To begin with, because of how Ionic components work, I couldn't get all the content to print, and I had to use some CSS rules I found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/css-media-query-for-printing-scrollable-content/73076/2) (also at the end).

After that, I was able to print the entire page to PDF using the browser print to pdf.

Or so I thought.

I noticed the second problem: not always the entire content was printed to PDF. Sometimes part of the content was just cut off.

Out of the *n* pages the PDF should have to display all of my questions, it decided to stop at *n-2*. My last *x* questions were cut off the printed pdf.

I have done some tests and identified the following behaviors:

- (Chrome) When accessing the page, it correctly displays all of my 100 questions/answers
- (Chrome) When using "Emulate CSS media" for "print" media type, it also correctly displays all of my 100 Q/A
- (Chrome) When using Ctrl+P, it cuts my last *n* questions
- (Edge) When using Ctrl+P, it prints only the first page
- (FireFox) When using Ctrl+P, it prints the entire content, all of the questions, but include some huge spaces in between questions

I fear I might be going to the wrong direction for printing long Ionic Pages. Or if not, how can I achieve a stable behaviour across the browsers? And how can I ensure all of my content is actually printed to the generated PDF?

```
    @media print {
    body {
        position: static;
        overflow: initial;
    }
    ion-nav {
        overflow: initial !important;
    }
    .scroll-content {
        position: relative;
        overflow:visible!important;
    }
    ion-header {
        display: none !important;
    }
    header nav, footer {
        display: none;
    }
    button {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .pane {
        position: initial;
    }
    p a {
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .app-root, .ion-page, ion-app, ion-nav, ion-tab, ion-tabs {
        contain: none;
    }
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Edge v42/17 will limit to first page if an element is `position: absolute`, changing to `relative !important` fixes it. Firefox v63 limits to first page if an element is `display: flex`, so change to `block !important`